# Generic autowire fails with no bean defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, abstract-class

This is going to be somewhat long, but I am simply trying to learn fancy things using spring 4.1.7

The problem that I am facing is that spring doesn't like that there is no bean declared for R and W in the Reader and Writer Controllers. Everything compiles but during runtime nothing works and I get error

```
Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected carefree.coding.dao.CommerceReaderDAO carefree.coding.controllers.rest.CommerceReaderController.reader; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set carefree.coding.dao.CommerceReaderDAO field carefree.coding.controllers.rest.CommerceReaderController.reader to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57
```

I have a simple DAO class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommerceObject
{
    public enum Type
    {
        USER
    }

    @Transient
    protected Type type;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected long id;

    public CommerceObject(Type type)
    {
        this.type = type;
        setId(-1l);
    }

    public Type getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(CommerceObject object)
    {
        return getId() == object.getId() && getType().equals(object.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

    public CommerceObject fromString(String json)
    {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, getClass());
    }

    public abstract boolean update(CommerceObject object);

    public abstract CommerceObject copy();

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No hashing for game objects");
    }
}
```

Which is extended by

```
@Entity(name = "user")
public class User extends CommerceObject
{
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public User()
    {
        super(Type.USER);
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(CommerceObject object)
    {
        if (object instanceof User)
        {
            User user = (User) object;
            if (equals(user))
            {
                user.setEmail(email);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public CommerceObject copy()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail(getEmail());
        return user;
    }
}
```

For reading and writing things to database I have two interfaces

**Reader**

```
public interface CommerceReaderInterface<V extends CommerceObject>
{
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    List<V> get();

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    V get(long id);
}
```

**Writer**

```
public interface CommerceWriterInterface<V extends CommerceObject>
{
    @Transactional
    V add(V v);

    @Transactional
    V update(V v);

    @Transactional
    V delete(V v);
}
```

Basic database access class

```
public abstract class CommerceDAO
{
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected Class aClass;

    public CommerceDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Class aClass)
    {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        this.aClass = aClass;
    }
}
```

Which allows reader and writer to exist

**Reader**

```
public class CommerceReaderDAO<V extends CommerceObject> extends CommerceDAO implements CommerceReaderInterface<V>
{
    public CommerceReaderDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Class aClass)
    {
        super(sessionFactory, aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public List<V> get()
    {
        ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(aClass);
        if (hibernateMetadata == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister)
        {
            AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;
            String tableName = persister.getTableName();
            if (tableName != null)
            {
                return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                        createQuery(tableName).list();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(long id)
    {
        V object = (V) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                get(aClass, id);
        Hibernate.initialize(object);
        return object;
    }
}
```

**Writer**

```
public class CommerceWriterDAO<V extends CommerceObject> extends CommerceDAO implements CommerceWriterInterface<V>
{
    public CommerceWriterDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Class aClass)
    {
        super(sessionFactory, aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public V add(V v)
    {
        if (v != null)
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(v);
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V update(V v)
    {
        if (v != null)
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(v);
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V delete(V v)
    {
        if (v != null)
        {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(v);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush();
            return v;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And for controllers I decided to do same thing and have a reader and writer interface

**Reader**

```
public interface CommerceReaderInterface
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> get();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> get(@PathVariable long id);
}
```

**Writer**

```
public interface CommerceWriterInterface<V extends CommerceObject>
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody V v);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/update",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> update(@RequestBody V v);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity<String> delete(@RequestBody V v);
}
```

And they are implemented normally

**Reader**

```
public abstract class CommerceReaderController<R extends CommerceReaderDAO<V>, V extends CommerceObject> implements CommerceReaderInterface
{
    @Autowired
    protected R reader;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> get()
    {
        List<V> list = reader.get();
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
        {
            return ResponseUtil.notFound();
        }
        return ResponseUtil.ok(list);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> get(@PathVariable long id)
    {
        V object = reader.get(id);
        if (object == null)
        {
            return ResponseUtil.notFound();
        }
        return ResponseUtil.ok(object);
    }
}
```

**Writer**

```
public abstract class CommerceWriterController<W extends CommerceWriterDAO<V>, R extends CommerceReaderDAO<V>, V extends CommerceObject> extends CommerceReaderController<R, V> implements CommerceWriterInterface<V>
{
    @Autowired
    protected W writer;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody V v)
    {
        v = writer.add(v);
        if (v == null)
        {
            return ResponseUtil.notFound();
        }
        return ResponseUtil.ok(v);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> update(@RequestBody V v)
    {
        v = writer.update(v);
        if (v == null)
        {
            return ResponseUtil.notFound();
        }
        return ResponseUtil.ok(v);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> delete(@RequestBody V v)
    {
        v = writer.delete(v);
        if (v == null)
        {
            return ResponseUtil.notFound();
        }
        return ResponseUtil.ok(v);
    }
}
```

After all that work I thought that having a simple controller would be allowed

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/commerce/api/user")
public class UserController extends CommerceWriterController<UserWriterDAO, UserReaderDAO, User>
{
}
```

However as I understand in my abstract controllers I am not allowed to have such vague DAO objects. Is there any way I can circumvent this?

Comment: You've made this unnecessarily long and you're still missing things. What is `UserWriterDAO`? What is `UserReaderDAO`? Why do you have so many generic layers? This is going to be a maintenance nightmare when you need specific behavior for a single type. Don't get too comfortable with this pattern.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this is simply trying to see how many layers I can add on. It is not any code that will be used anywhere, but I simply want to make framework for basic CRUD functionality for any object I want. Also how would you shorten it? Feel free to shorten my question :)

Comment: For one, I can't immediately tell what the problem is from reading your question. Are you getting an error? What do you mean _vague DAO objects_? If you're saying it's a compilation error on the type declarations, the implementation (the bodies) of the classes don't matter.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis done, added the error and exactly what happens when I try to run it.